# Deleting a 340 mode directories

Tags: php, directory, chmod

I once used this wrong PHP script which created a 340 mode directories:

```
<?php
 $uname = "secret";
 mkdir("/home/u251526215/public_html/user/profile/".$uname."", 755);
?>
```

The script above creates a 340 CHMOD directories. I've repaired the "755" to "0755" and it is now working perfectly. But for now, how can I delete the 340 directories which were already created? I have tried to delete them using FTP manager, but it kept saying error. I've tried to use rmdir() but it says directory not empty but it is completely empty!

**Updated**: All action to the directory; rename, move, copy, change permission and open are error returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a hidden file. I found this function to delete a directory with all contents:

```
function delete_directory($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
}
```

Source http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/php-delete-directory-folder-t47492.html

Comment: The script doesn't delete the direcory. I've supplied the $dirname with "**abah**", one of my 340 folder. Link (http://greenwap.net.tf/user/profile/abah). Is it invulnureable? It is really disturbing my parent directory

Comment: Try the full path or maybe `exec('rm -R full/path/abah')`